# How to customise top navigation links and their contents on Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

I have a couple of questions regarding Facebook profile pages.

1. I noticed that when I go to my friends' profiles on Facebook, the links at the top
   of the profile differ from friend to friend. For instance, one friend has entries
   "Timeline, About, Photos, Friends, More: Places, Sports, Music, Films, TV Programmes,
   Books, Likes, Events, Groups, Review, Notes", while another friend also has an entry
   under More called "Apps and Games", and yet another friend has an entry under More
   called "Foursquare". How can these links found on the top of one's own profile page
   be customized?
2. I notice that with one friend when I click on "Friends" on the profile's top
   navigation bar I get a subnavigation bar with entries named "All Friends,
   University, High School, Current City", while on another friend's profile
   when I click on "Friends" I get a subnavigation bar with entries "All Friends,
   Mutual Friends, Recently Added, High School, More: People you may know, Following".
   Why are these entries in the profile Friends subnavigation bar different. Even more
   puzzling, and perhaps even more interesting, is how come one other friend only has
   "Mutual Friends, Followers" in this subnavigation bar and there is no "All Friends"
   link where I would view all of this friend's friends? On yet another friend's
   profile, when I click on "Friends" no sub-navigation bar shows up and instead I
   see the message "No friends to show". Why do these subnavigation bars differ,
   and more importantly, how can I configure them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change which sections of your timeline are available to view.
Hover your mouse pointer over any box on your own timeline and look for the "Pencil" icon that shows up, via the "Manage Sections" optoin, it allows you to edit the visibility of that box, some boxes (such as your friends list page) also allow you to edit the privacy of that box.

Comment: Thank you. I see the button with the Pencil icon on every header entry on my Profile except for Timeline and About. Clicking on this icon reveals the "Manage Sections" option which you mention (which is also available at the bottom of the More header entry under the name "Manage Sections". Presumably the header entries themselves are determined by which Facebook applications I have installed. Timeline, About, Photos, and Friends, are the only entries that cannot be hidden (these entries are grayed out). Thanks.

Comment: To hide your Friends list from your friends one can achieve the effect by going to the Friends box at the top of the Profile, selecting Edit Privacy from the drop-down menu, and setting Friend List to Only Me in the pop-up window. Thanks.